# netstat process details with the IP address

Tags: linux, networking, netstat

My netstat command is as below on the Centos machine

```
#netstat -n | grep 172.18.0.6 | more
tcp        0      0 172.18.0.1:57332        172.18.0.6:8444         FIN_WAIT2
```

I want to find out which process is running with the IP address 172.18.0.1 . Any way to find out the same

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: Use the `-p` option to get the PID and process name.

Comment: @Barmar I propose that this, although in current usage *is* command line, could be useful to future users as these commands may be used in a bash script for a larger, more complete, command "set".  So theoretically it *could* be programing?

Comment: @Zak That's true of almost any Linux command. That doesn't make it a programming question.

Comment: I respectfully disagree [When is a question about a Unix command complicated enough to be a programming question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366220/when-is-a-question-about-a-unix-command-complicated-enough-to-be-a-programming-q?answertab=votes#tab-top). --  Not to say this question could not have been researched more, and answered on it's own .. But I fall into the category of "if it's a command, it's programming"

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for the `netstat` `-p` option.

`#netstat -np | grep 172.18.0.6 | more`

Should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lsof`.

If you want to see which service is running in port `57332`:

```
lsof -i TCP:57332
```

or by IP:

```
lsof -i |grep 172.18.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
netstat -apn | grep 172.18.0.6 | more
```

to get also the sockets that are listening.